# why isn't awk printing all records?

Tags: awk

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

Here is my input:

`$ cat haldvr.txt
StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
av files count: 3
record[0]: id: 0xB91EDF42
         name          : ''
         time_cr       : 0x5B0F5722
         size_bytes    : 0x000000007249D25C
         size_seconds  : 0x00000705
         bit_rate      : 0x00000000
         attributes    : 0x00000004
record[1]: id: 0x8F65A842
         name          : ''
         time_cr       : 0x5B060E92
         size_bytes    : 0x00000000E692A554
         size_seconds  : 0x00000E0C
         bit_rate      : 0x00000000
         attributes    : 0x00000004
record[2]: id: 0x9B516A42
         name          : ''
         time_cr       : 0x5B08B192
         size_bytes    : 0x00000001E3C17DAA
         size_seconds  : 0x00001C1E
         bit_rate      : 0x00000000
         attributes    : 0x00000004
haldvr ls finished -> 0`

Here is the output I want (or something very similar):

`StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
    av files count: 3
Record ID         Name   Time                Mbytes   Length
     0  0xB91EDF42  ''    2018-05-30 08:00:02 1828.61  29:57
     1  0x8F65A842  ''    2018-05-23 07:00:02 3689.17  59:56
     3  0x9B516A42  ''    2018-05-25 07:00:02 7740.09  59:58`

Here is my attempt:

```
$ cat bin/haldvr1.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN           {print("Record\tID\tName\tDate\tMbytes\tLength\n")}
/StorageHandle/ {print $0}
/av files/      {print $0}
/record/        {record=$1}
/name/          {name=$3}
/time_cr/       {time_cr=$3}
/size_bytes/    {mbytes=$3}
/size_seconds/  {dur=$3}
/bit_rate/      {bitrate=$3}
/attributes/    {attributes=$3}
END             {printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\n",record,id,strftime("%F %T",strtonum(time_cr)),strtonum(mbytes)/1024/1024,strftime("%M:%S",strtonum(dur)))}
```

Here is my result:

```
$ cat haldvr.txt | bin/haldvr1.awk
Record  ID      Name    Date    Mbytes  Length

StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
av files count: 3
record[2]:              2018-05-25 19:00:02     7740.093180     59:58
```

Why is it only printing 1 record instead of 3?

I'll fix the formatting later. But I don't understand why only 1 record is being printed out.

Comment: `END` is run at the end of the input. You should print the record data when processing the "attributes" field of each record.

Comment: Every time you find a `/record/` or ` /name/` or ` /time_cr/` etc.. you overwrite your variables to whatever it just found. At the end of processing the file you print whatever is left in those variables. Instead you should run that `printf(...` logic whenever you find a `/record/`  like `/record/        {printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\n",record,id,strftime("%F %T",strtonum(time_cr)),strtonum(mbytes)/1024/1024,strftime("%M:%S",strtonum(dur))); record=$1}` keeping the `END` block as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
function print_record() {
    if ("id" in rec) {
        if (! printed_header) {
            print "Record","ID","Name","Time","Mbytes","Length"
            printed_header = 1
        }
        print rec["num"], \
              rec["id"], \
              rec["name"], \
              strftime("%F %T", strtonum( rec["time_cr"] )), \
              strtonum( rec["size_bytes"] ) / 1024 / 1024, \
              strftime("%M:%S", strtonum( rec["size_seconds"] ))
        delete rec
    }
}
$1 == "StorageHandle:" || $1 == "av" {print; next}
/^record/ {
    print_record()
    if (split($0,a,/[][]/)) { rec["num"] = a[2] }
    rec["id"] = $NF
}
/^[[:blank:]]/ { rec[$1] = $3 }
END {print_record()}
```

outputs

```
awk -f haldvr1.awk haldvr.txt
```

```
StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
av files count: 3
Record  ID      Name    Time    Mbytes  Length
0       0xB91EDF42      ''      2018-05-30 22:00:02     1828.61 29:57
1       0x8F65A842      ''      2018-05-23 21:00:02     3689.17 59:56
2       0x9B516A42      ''      2018-05-25 21:00:02     7740.09 59:58
```

For prettier output, you can do:

```
awk -f haldvr1.awk haldvr.txt | { 
    IFS= read -r h1; echo "$h1"
    IFS= read -r h2; echo "$h2"
    column -t -s $'\t'
}
```

```
StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
av files count: 3
Record  ID          Name  Time                 Mbytes   Length
0       0xB91EDF42  ''    2018-05-30 22:00:02  1828.61  29:57
1       0x8F65A842  ''    2018-05-23 21:00:02  3689.17  59:56
2       0x9B516A42  ''    2018-05-25 21:00:02  7740.09  59:58
```

Answer (score 0):

Glenn beat me to the punch but I'll throw out my solution here anyways.  Your problem was due to the fact you were only printing at the end, so only the last records information was present to be printed.  You need to print every time you hit a new record and at the end to print the last record.

Here is the code I used to make the formatting like you are shooting for.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=": "
        }
/Handle/{print $0}
/count/{print "AV File Counts "$2}
/record/{
        if (arr["id"]!=""){
                printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\n",arr["record"],arr["id"],arr["name"],strftime("%F %T",arr["time_cr"]),arr["size_bytes"]/1024/1024,strftime("%M:%S",arr["size_seconds"]))
        }
        else
                print("Record\tID\tName\tDate\tMbytes\tLength")
        arr["id"]=$3
        sub(".*\\[","",$1)
        sub("].*","",$1)
        arr["record"]=$1
        }
$1!~"record"{
        gsub(" ","",$1)
        if($2 ~ "0x") {
                gsub(" ","",$2)
                $2=strtonum($2)
        }
        arr[$1]=$2
}
END {
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\n",arr["record"],arr["id"],arr["name"],strftime("%F %T",arr["time_cr"]),arr["size_bytes"]/1024/1024,strftime("%M:%S",arr["size_seconds"]))
}
```

**Output**

```
StorageHandle: 0xDEADBEAFDEAD0001
AV File Counts 3
Record  ID      Name    Date    Mbytes  Length
0       0xB91EDF42      ''      2018-05-30 20:00:02     1828.613857     29:57
1       0x8F65A842      ''      2018-05-23 19:00:02     3689.165363     59:56
2       0x9B516A42      ''      2018-05-25 19:00:02     7740.093180     59:58
```